# How to avoid some windows services being loaded at user login

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, group-policy

we have some Terminal Servers based on Windows 2016 and 2019, we're currently implementing GPO in order to avoid some services ( user services like Xbox Live Game Save, Sync Host and so on.. ) being loaded at the user login.

Before implementing gpo, which is the recommended way though, we did use some reg keys to accomplish our goal.

Now, inside task manager, we do see those services as "disabled" but we're afraid that this fact will consume CPU and RAM ( yeah the services are disabled and not running but we see loads of those ) .

Is there any possible way to prevent the OS to show them inside the task manager ? Are these services going to consume our cpu/memory resources as they're loaded for every user logged-in ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

A disabled service is just a database entry on the disk, no process and no memory is assigned to a service which does not run (no running process - no used memory & cpu!). These services are not loaded on user login, so there is no need to stop that service from showing in that list.

If you still want to do this, there are two ways:

- revoke access rights to the correct registry key representing the service ( `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\xxxxx` (if you really want to do this rightclick on the key (folder icon), open permissions, and click on "Deny" of all rights of the `SYSTEM` account
- **!!!DANGEROUS!!!** completely delete the service: [Link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-windows-service-in-vista-or-xp/)

Comment: Thank you very much Martin !